# PHPStorm Xdebug not working

Tags: magento2, xdebug, phpcs

I would like to configure and check the code flow using the X-debug break-point, so I followed the below tutorial and successfully configured the X-debug in my PHP-storm, I am using php-7.2

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html

Then I set some break point and tried to understand the flow of the coding, but when ever I reload the page, it always start working from index.php after the php.cs and php-cs-fixed.

I've tried lot but still I wasn't able to find the best way to make work the xdebug in my machine.

[image: PHP and XDebug version]

In my local I've installed the X-debug Version-2.9.8 and it's working fine.
It starts from magentoroot/index.php then jumps into the phpcs and php-cs-fixed file.

Thanks in advance for your great support.

Comment: you may add xdebug version installed. also, you seem to tell us you can see xdebug works currently? and your problem is that you are constantly stopped with php.cs, can you confirm these? so that I understand exactly where you are..

Comment: @HerveTribouilloy I've updated the question with some additional details

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a Magento related question.